# Open Graph video.watches action with Youtube API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, youtube-api

Does anyone know if it's possible to create an Open graph **video.watches** action from embedded youtube video (using Youtube API and Open graph)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with javascript using Open Graph API:

Reference › Open Graph Action Types › video.watches:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/video.watches

And you can do the same on Google+ using Moments:

https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert

using AddActivity

https://developers.google.com/+/api/moment-types/add-activity

And you should use the YouTube player events to call functions that works with actions

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events